# Codeigniter - добавление массива в сессию

Tags: codeigniter

Добавляю массив

```
$this->settings
```

в сессию так:

```
$this->CI->session->set_userdata(array('GLOBAL_LANG_COUNTRY' => $this->settings));
```

Но при получении данных из сессии по имени - ничего нет:

```
$this->CI->session->userdata('GLOBAL_LANG_COUNTRY');
```

Comment: print_r($this->CI->session->userdata('GLOBAL_LANG_COUNTRY'));
что получаешь?

Comment: False, а если заменить на ($_SESSION['GLOBAL_LANG_COUNTRY'], то выводит массив из сессии

Comment: В общем взял это решение, видимо это проблема CI:
http://www.philsbury.co.uk/blog/code-igniter-sessions

Comment: Оказалось - она не работает с DB.